# WPF Mahapps: UserControl doesn't trigger event

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a MetroWindow for the main window. Inside it there is a control (x) with another control (y) inside it. The y control has a DataGrid with an event setted on MouseDoubleClick.

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ProdottiGridRow_Click"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns> ...
```

The event doesn't work (not triggered), no Exception is thrown.
With a normal Window (in place of MetroWindow) the code works!
Are there specific rules to follow for insert a UserControl inside a MetroWindow?

Comment: Download the latest version of MahApps. They fixed some bugs, which related to Hit test in MetroWindow. That may help you.

Comment: Thanks @XAMLLover. I have v 1.0.0. There is on GitHub v 1.0.1, but is Alpha at this moment.

Comment: Since the event does not route through the visual tree, you could try MouseDoubleClick on DataGrid (not dataGridRow) and handle the selected row.

Comment: Yes, the event on the DataGrid works. I'm not expert with WPF, but I think Mahapps overwrite my EventSetter when it sets its own style to the DataGridRow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the `RowStyle` and not set the `ItemContainerStyle`

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"
          BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroDataGridRow}">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                  Handler="ProdottiGridRow_Click" />
  </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, it works. But I don't understand the difference. I used the previous solution after reading a discussion on stackoverflow. Thanks @punker.